# Summing up numbers recursively not working

Tags: python, recursion

I'm learning about recursion in Python. However, Python is being weird:

```
def listsum(numslist, _total=0):
if len(numslist) > 1:
    _total += numslist[-1]
    print("Total is %d" % _total)
    numslist = numslist[:-1]
    listsum(numslist, _total)
else:
    _total += numslist[-1]
    print("Returning %d" % _total)
    return _total


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(listsum([10, 10, 10]))
```

For me it returns:

```
Total is 10
Total is 20
Returning 30
None
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit (fixed)

```
    listsum(numslist, _total)
```

Should be

```
    return listsum(numslist, _total)
```

Comment: When `else` is not reached, the function will return `None` by default, that's why you're getting it printed.

Comment: That was stupid. Fixed now!

Comment: This is the single most common mistake with recursive functions I see on SO.

Comment: What is wrong with `sum` and `reduce` ?

Comment: The indentation within the function is wrong. It couldn't work that way. Can you please adapt it according to your original code, so that it can't confuse newbies.

Comment: I really don't understand what you expect your code to do.

Comment: It's just a code assignment on using recursion in python. I'm familiar with the sum bif, but that wasn't the point.